# Form.Focus InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, .net-4.5

I'm clearly checking `InvokeRequired` here, but that is returning false, followed by the form throwing an InvalidOperationException. What am I doing wrong?

```
/// <summary>Position the specified form within the specified bounds,
/// and focus it, all in a thread-safe manner.</summary>
private static void FocusForm_Helper(Form form, double top, double height, double left, double width)
{
    if (form?.IsDisposed ?? true)
        return;
    if (form.InvokeRequired)
    {
        form.Invoke((Action)(() => FocusForm_Helper(form, top, height, left, width)));
        return;
    }
    form.Top = (int)(top + 0.5 * (height /*- form.Height*/));
    form.Left = (int)(left + 0.5 * (width /*- form.Width*/));
    form.Focus();
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'DataUploadDialog' accessed from a thread other than the
>   thread it was created on.
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_CanFocus()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.FocusInternal()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Focus()    at
>   ExcelDNA.CustomRibbon.FocusForm_Helper(Form form, Double top, Double
>   height, Double left, Double width)

I created this control on the main thread and then ran it on a separate thread so that it has its own message pump. I then invoke focus on the control expecting it to detect InvokeRequired as necessary and invoke "Focus" on the appropriate thread, but it isn't happening.

```
_launchedDataUploadDialog = new DataUploadDialog();
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(_launchedDataUploadDialog);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data upload utility halted unexpectedly.\n\n" + ex);
        _launchedDataUploadDialog = null;
    }
});
thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
FocusForm(_launchedDataUploadDialog);
```

Comment: It complains about a `DataUploadDialog`, did you construct some controls on different threads perhaps?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The form is created on the main thread but run from a thread with its own apartment state. I've updated the questions to show that.

Comment: Why are you recursing into itself?

Comment: @t0mm13b That is a normal trick for `InvokeRequired` methods.

Comment: Hang on, you are clearly *creating* the form on your main thread, then you *run* it on another. You should be creating the form on that thread as well.

Comment: Sure it may be a trick, but a trick is hiding something there, why call itself again when cross threading. Simplify it, create a simple function to set the form bounds, and call `Invoke` on that, else call another function that is in the domain of the thread itself. Just for debugging it to confirm that it is calling the method. Surely a stack overflow would happen if recursing into itself in context of thread?

Comment: You added 2 race bugs in the code.  The IsDisposed check is meaningless, it does not guarantee that the form is not disposed when execution arrives at InvokeRequired.  InvokeRequired does not guarantee that it is no longer necessary when execution arrives at the Invoke() call.  This can and *will* go wrong.  Displaying forms on a worker thread is also a very bad idea, you will have to get familiar with [this kind of debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/) scenario.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant How can the value of InvokeRequired change before a call to Invoke? You'd have to somehow move the entire executing context to a new thread.

Comment: The lifetime of the form object is determined by another thread.  It runs completely asynchronous from your worker thread.  So it can die at any time.  Or for that matter come alive at any time, it will also fail when you start the thread too soon.  There is no synchronization in your code visible at all so there is nothing to stop this from happening.  You are supposed to be a lot more worried about that link I posted btw.

Comment: Yeah I get how  IsDisposed is a race condition, that's why I have a catch elsewhere. I want to know how `InvokeRequired` can be a in a race condition with invoke. Not only does that seem impossible, but it would invalidate what is a very common pattern in the industry. Your statement `InvokeRequired does not guarantee that it is no longer necessary when execution arrives at the Invoke() call.` seems wrong.

Comment: @Alain I'm confused: Why are you creating the form on the outer thread, and not the one running it, at Application.Run?

Comment: I need a handle on the form in the main thread so I can interact with it. What's more, if the handle is created in the thread that runs it, you cannot invoke anything on the form because the owning thread is of course dedicated to the Application.Run message pump.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution in this case is that the `Focus()` method does not act on the form itself, but the main control displayed by the form. When the form has its own apartment state because it was invoked by `Application.Run`, its `InvokeRequired` isn't relevant - that of its main control is.

So the solution is:

```
if (form.Controls[0].InvokeRequired)
{
    form.Controls[0].BeginInvoke((Action)(() => ...));
    return;
}
form.Focus();
```